# Shell JQ : Format output to specific string with delimeter

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I want to have an output that instead of delimeter **space** it should be like this **", "** using **jq**

**nodes.json**

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "node1.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    },
    "node2.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    },
    "node3.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.3",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my command use

```
ips=`cat /vagrant/nodes.json | jq -r '.nodes | to_entries[] | [.value.":ip"] | @tsv'`
echo [\"$ips\"]
```

where the output is

```
["10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3"]
```

and i want it to be like this

```
["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ jq -c '.nodes | to_entries | map(.value.":ip")' input
["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2","10.0.0.3"]
```

Comment: how about if I want to make it like this , with static port
["10.0.0.1:4646", "10.0.0.2:4646", "10.0.0.3:4646"]

Comment: i created another thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599778/jq-output-with-static-value