# JQ : Output with static value / variable

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I want to have an output with static value using jq with static value **:4546**

**nodes.json**

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "node1.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    },
    "node2.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    },
    "node3.local": {
      ":ip": "10.0.0.3",
      "ports": [],
      ":memory": 1024,
      ":bootstrap": "bootstrap.sh"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my command use

```
ips=`jq -c '.nodes | to_entries | map(.value.":ip")' nodes.json`
echo $ips
```

where the output is

```
["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3"]
```

and i want it to be like this

```
["10.0.0.1:4546", "10.0.0.2:4546", "10.0.0.3:4546"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map_values`

```
 jq -c '.nodes | to_entries | map(.value.":ip")| map_values(.+":4546")' nodes.jso
```

Answer (score 3):

Another try :

```
jq '[.nodes[][":ip"]+":4546"]' nodes.json
```

Comment: One adjustment I would suggest would be to prefer string interpolation over string concatenation whenever possible. `["\(.nodes[][":ip"]):4546"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use + operator:

```
jq '.nodes | to_entries | map(.value.":ip" + ":4546")'
```